# NSPredicate and NSArray of tokens

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have asked this in the past but couldn't get a clear answer.
I have an object in CoreData like this, KeyWord(word, chapter)

```
Word      Chapter
cold      chapter1
cold      chapter2
cold      chapter3
weather   chapter1
weather   chapter2
humidity  chapter7
Florida   chapter8
Florida   chapter9
```

I would like the user to search for any of these words as in "cold Florida weather .."
So, I broke the search into an `NSArray *tokens = [search.text compnentsSeparatedBy:@" "];`

Currently, I have this predicate which kinda works:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat@"word contains[cd]%@ AND word contains [cd]%@",words[0],words[1],words[2]..]
```

But, the problem is that I don't know how many words the user will type in, so, Is there a way to search the column 'word' using NSArray of tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

`[NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:/*Your Array Of Contains Predicates Here*/]`

Although I'm unclear from your question if you want to be using the `IN` command to search an array/set of objects.

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"word IN %@", setOfWords]`

Comment: Thanks - Before I check out NSCompundPredicate - I would like to check your second suggestion. If I have NSArray *tokens = {cold,weather, Florida}, these are the words to search for, Can I use [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"column In %@", tokens]? Will this handle case sensitive as well if I do [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"column In [cd] %@", tokens] ?

Comment: The `IN` command will return all objects that contain one of the tokens. Not sure about `[cd]` sorry.

Comment: 'IN' would have worked for me if ti wasn't for case sensitivity. [cd] didn't appear to work. I will check NSCompoundPredicate.

Comment: Compound OR predicate would let you use contains[cd]. Just a thought.